# Masonry - Can't Find Variable imagesLoaded

Tags: jquery, javascript, errors

So I am current building a site with the pieces theme which has built in masonry. When the theme was stock, the masonry was working however as I have begun to make modifications to the theme I have now noticed the error "Can't find variable imagesLoaded". I would just go back to stock and re-make the theme with my customisations being careful to check for errors after each change however that is going to take too long. I thought I would ask here to see if anyone else has had this issue recently. I know there is one other question on here similar to this and I tried to use the code from that but was slightly unsure about exactly what to do with it. Could it be that I loaded jQuery in the header.php for a custom jQuery dropdown menu I put in? The masonry code from the functions.php file is as follows:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) :
        // Deregister built in masonry since it is old version 3.
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-masonry' );

        // Load imagesLoaded plugin.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'imagesLoaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', false, null, true );

        // Load newer masonry.
        wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array( 'imagesLoaded'), null, true );

    endif;
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that by removing the footer.php file, I was removing a link to the function wp_footer(); which essentially does this:

```
function wp_footer() {
    /**
     * Print scripts or data before the closing body tag on the front end.
     *
     * @since 1.5.1
     */
    do_action( 'wp_footer' );
}
```